# jQuery Ajax with Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these Javascript classes/code:

```
function PageManager () {
    this.digital_channels = undefined;

    this.loadConfiguration = function () {
        this.digital_channels = new Array ();
        var self = this;

        $.ajax ("path_to_server",
                {
                    type: "post",
                    cache: true,
                    context: self,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var self = $(this);
                        $xmlDoc = $($.parseXML (data));
                        $xmlDoc.find ("channel".each (function () {
                            self.digital_channels.push (new DigitalChannel ($(this)));
                        });
                    }
                });
    }
}

function DigitalChannel ($xmlDoc) {
    // Object: parse XML and construct here
}
```

Inside of the AJAX success method, `var self = $(this);` is my attempt to save what I thought would be the class object. `self.digital_channels.push (new DigitalChannel ($(this)));` is supposed to construct a new DigitalChannel object with `$(this)` being the current XML DOM object. I want that new object to go into my array. The array is always undefined at this point.

Can somebody explain how I do this?

Comment: Javascript does not have classes.

Comment: why do you define the array as undefined? Since it is a private var you could define it as an empty Array.

Comment: The general idea is that I want it undefined until I load the configuration so that I know the configuration isn't loaded.

Comment: Javascript doesn't call them "classes", but that's really what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mixing and overcomplicating things here. Try the following:

```
function PageManager ()
{
  this.digital_channels = undefined;
  this.loadConfiguration = function () {
  this.digital_channels = new Array ();
  //var self = this; // Remove this

    $.ajax ("path_to_server",
            {
                type: "post",
                cache: true,
                context: this, // Change to `this`
                success: function (data) {
                    var that = this; // instance of PageManager
                    $xmlDoc = $($.parseXML(data));
                    $xmlDoc.find ("channel").each (function () {
                        that.digital_channels.push (new DigitalChannel ($(this)));
                    });
                }
            });
   }
}
```

Comment: Also works. Thank you as well, I figured I had to be making it harder than it really was.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to remove the line `var self = $(this);` from the success function. self is already defined before the ajax request, and will contain the reference to your PageManager object. This reference variable should be able to be used within the success handler too.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to investigate "closure scope" now.